# Hollow Rectangle user input. Using a nested loop with 1 if else statement

Tags: c#, loops, nested

I can't figure out how to  print the right side. What I have so far will print the top, left side, and the bottom.

```
        Console.WriteLine("How many columns wide should the rectangle be?");
        int iCol = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("How many rows tall should the rectangle be?");
        int iRow = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Here you go: ");

        for (int row = 0; row < iRow; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < iCol; col++)
            {
                if (row == 0 || col  == 0|| col +1 == iCol|| row + 1== iRow)                        
                {
                    Console.Write("*");                        

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Top and bottom rows: `Console.WriteLine(new string('*', iRow));` Middle rows: `Console.WriteLine("*" + new string('*', iRow - 2) + "*");`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Bychenko I already have the top and bottom rows

Answer (score 1):

Replace the space WriteLine() by Write() works..

```
    Console.WriteLine("How many columns wide should the rectangle be?");
    int iCol = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("How many rows tall should the rectangle be?");
    int iRow = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Here you go: ");

    for (int row = 0; row < iRow; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < iCol; col++)
        {
            if (row == 0 || col  == 0|| col +1 == iCol|| row + 1== iRow)                        
            {
                Console.Write("*");                        

            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(" ");   // this will do
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Lil, welcome to SO. Tip: if you got stuck on something like this, relax, take a cup of black tea and 15 minutes break, then look again.